# Create a Seq of Elements based on Increment in Scala

Tags: scala, generics

I have a need to generate a sequence of elements of a certain Numeric type with a certain start and end and with the given increment. Here is what I came up with:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat

  def round(elem: Double): Double = {
    val df2 = new DecimalFormat("###.##")
    df2.format(elem).toDouble
  }

  def arrange(start: Double, end: Double, increment: Double): Seq[Double] = {
    @scala.annotation.tailrec
    def recurse(acc: Seq[Double], start: Double, end: Double): Seq[Double] = {
      if (start >= end) acc
      else recurse(acc :+ round(start + increment), round(start + increment), end)
    }
    recurse(Seq.empty[Double], start, end)
  }

  arrange(0.0, 0.55, 0.05) foreach println
```

This works as expected and gives me the following result:

```
0.05
0.1
0.15
0.2
0.25
0.3
0.35
0.4
0.45
0.5
0.55
```

However, I would like to see if I can make this generic so that the same function works for an Int, Long, Float. Is there a way to simplify this?

Comment: Yup use [`Numeric`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Numeric.html) _(which is a [**typeclas**](https://tpolecat.github.io/2013/10/12/typeclass.html))_. - BTW, you may want to use a `List` and prepend _(with a `reverse` in the end)_ or use a `Vector`; since that code can be extremely inefficient. - PS: The stdlib already has such functionality in cases you didn't know; but I guess this is just an exercise to learn the language.

Comment: Which function is that?

Comment: [`List.range`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List$.html#range[A](start:A,end:A,step:A)(implicitevidence$4:Integral[A]):CC[A]) - Well, actually you can replace `List` with any collection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Came across this much simpler version:

```
@ BigDecimal(0.0) to BigDecimal(0.5) by BigDecimal(0.05) 
res23: collection.immutable.NumericRange.Inclusive[BigDecimal] = NumericRange(0.0, 0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 0.25, 0.30, 0.35, 0.40, 0.45, 0.50)
```